# Database on time to churn in telecomunication

Tags: databases, churn

I would like to research about time to churn<sup>1</sup> in the telecommunication market. Does anyone have a link to such a database? The only ones [I found](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_a_big_data_set_publicly_or_privately_availablefor_churn_prediction_in_telecom) did not include the time of churn, but only **if** a customer is labeled as churn or non-churn, what I would need is time to event data.

The papers I researched all seemed to use private databases.

<sup>1</sup>churn is defined here as the moment in time, where a customer quits the service that he/she book from the service provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of the database, search dataset

https://www.google.com/search?q=telecomunication+churn+dataset&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

After searching some more, I found various datasets for churn prediction. Thank`s at parvij for the suggestion, that really helped!

These are a few datasets I found, which have a **binary target variable** (churn or no-churn):

https://www.crowdanalytix.com/contests/why-customer-churn

http://www.iainpardoe.com/teaching/dsc433/data.htm

https://www.kaggle.com/akhilsaichinthala/telecom-churn-data-singtel

https://github.com/lazycrazyowl/Wolfram-Summer-School-2017-Jassim-Moideen/blob/master/Project/Assets/churntest.csv

https://github.com/RichardAfolabi/Realtime-Data-Analytics-Using-Spark/blob/master/Analyzing%20Orange%20Telecoms%20Customer%20Churn%20Dataset.ipynb

https://bigml.com/user/francisco/gallery/dataset/5163ad540c0b5e5b22000383

Datasets I found using **time to event data**:

https://mineracaodedados.wordpress.com/2017/01/ This dataset contains time to event data, but the meaning of the data is not clearly explained.

https://www.ibm.com/communities/analytics/watson-analytics-blog/predictive-insights-in-the-telco-customer-churn-data-set/ with the label "tenures" indicating the time is already enrolled.